# How do I get sed to print a range of lines until it sees two consecutive blank lines?

Tags: sed

I'd like to use a sed script like this

```
#n
/^TODO/,/^$/p
```

except that sed should stop printing the range after it comes across two consecutive blank lines, rather than just one blank line. Then it should continue scanning for the next range of interest. In other words, the end of range of interest is defined by two blank lines. I'm not even sure that an address range can handle this sort of requirement, so if there's another way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: `sed` is a stream editor. For processing text based on the contents of *lines* it may be best to use another tool, such as **awk** or **perl**

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. But I thought some advanced sed involving H, N, n, etc. might still do the trick.

Comment: Yes it's possible with sed. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938281/how-do-i-get-sed-to-print-a-range-of-lines-until-it-sees-two-consecutive-blank-li/1938963#1938963 . P.S. I noticed you have yet to accept any answers for the four questions you have asked. It is good etiquette to do this as it benefits others who may have a similar problem as you. Also, I think you'll find that people will be more willing to provide you more in-depth answers if you do so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to this site and just figuring out how things work.

Comment: In the accepted answer, Edit 2 fails in three ways: 1) if the TODO block is an odd number of lines, the line following the pair of blank lines will be printed; 2) if the extra line from case 1 happens to be the start of another TODO block, none of the rest of that block will be printed; 3) if there is a single blank line on an odd numbered line in the block (counting the TODO line as #1) followed by a non-blank line then more lines in the block, the blank line will satisfy the end of the address range so the printing of the block will be truncated after the non-blank line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should stop when it encounters two consecutive blank lines regardless of the odd/even pairing of the blank lines with non-blank lines:

Don't print the two blank lines:

```
sed -n 'N;/^\n$/q;P;D'
```

Print one of them:

```
sed -n 'N;/^\n$/{P;q};P;D'
```

Print both of them:

```
sed -n 'N;/^\n$/{p;q};P;D'
```

**Edit:**

And here's how you'd make that work in your range:

```
sed -n '/^TODO/,${N;/^\n$/q;P;D}'
```

**Edit 2:**

Per **dan's** (the OP) comments and edited requirements, this seems to work to find the pattern in a range that ends in two blank lines, multiple times in a file:

```
sed -n '/^TODO/,/^$/{H;N;/^\n$/{b};p}'
```

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me. I had trouble getting it to work as a one-liner so I had to spread it out over a few lines in a sed script. When I tried it as a one-liner, I got this error: "extra characters at the end of D command". But it did work when I put each command on its own line. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I just noticed that this script stops working after hitting the 1 double-blank-lines. Ideally, I'd want it to continue scanning the file for the next similar pattern.

Comment: One thing is that different versions of `sed` behave differently. Someone had a similar error the other day. I wonder whether, instead, it has something to do with some strange Unicode thing. Did you copy and paste the command or did you type it in? If the former, try typing it by hand and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, in your question you said "stop printing".

Comment: You're right, I should have written "stop printing that range, but continue scanning for the next one" -- I'll edit my question.

Comment: Here's what I have so far: `sed -n '/^TODO/,/^$/{H;N;/^$/{p;b}};/^$/{x;p}'` - unfortunately, it skips some single blank lines and prints some more than once.

Comment: It looks like just moving the last brace after the D command to a separate line (in a sed script file) will make it work for me.

Comment: OK, it looks like it might be easier just to write a Ruby script for this.

Comment: Try this: `sed -n '/^TODO/,/^$/{H;N;/^\n$/{p;b};P};/^$/{x}'`

Comment: Or this: `sed -n '/^TODO/,/^$/{H;N;/^\n$/{b};p}'` - this seems to work, but it prints an extra line sometimes.

Comment: That actually seems to delete every other non-blank line in the lines following /^TODO/

Comment: This does not work for me. You seem to put stuff in the hold buffer but never retrieve it.

Comment: I see that you put a lot of work into this, but unfortunately using an address range with N is just too problematic, for the reasons I mention above.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
sed -n '/TODO/{:a;N;/\n\n$/s///p;Ta}' file
```

This will strictly adhere to the OP question and only print the range less the two newlines if each range includes two consecutive newlines.

If an end of file will also signify the end of such a range, use:

```
sed -n '/TODO/{:a;p;n;/^$/!ba;n;//b;x;p;x;ba}' file
```

N.B. The use of the hold space to supply a single blank line when it is not followed by another.

---

Also the first solution can print either two newlines:

```
sed -n '/TODO/{:a;N;/\n\n$/!ba;p}' file
```

Or one newline:

```
sed -n '/TODO/{:a;N;/\n\n$/s//\n/p;Ta}' file
```

Comment: You need `s/\n\n$//` otherwise it only prints the TODO line but not the rest of the TODO block.

Comment: @Jeff thanks. I don't know what I was thinking but I've rewritten my solutions instead of the faulty one.

Comment: If you had just done my fix, you'd have a better code golf score ;-) plus it has the advantage of being easily modified to print one or two trailing blanks by putting \n or & in the replacement.  But I learned some things from your new stuff, so I'm happy.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the :b in your second script :o)

Comment: @Jeff thanks I originally had the 2nd regexp as a positive and reduced it to a negative but forgot to remove the place holder.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use an address range

Instead, look for the start of the TODO block, then loop until you find the pair of blank lines.

Here is a test file.  After that is a comparison of some of the proposed solutions.

```
cat >tricky_todo.txt <<EOF
TODO block 1 line 1 (last line)


THIS LINE SHOULDN'T BE PRINTED #1
THIS LINE SHOULDN'T BE PRINTED #2
TODO block 2 line 1
     block 2 line 2
     block 2 line 3
     block 2 line 4

     block 2 line 6
     block 2 line 7
     block 2 line 8 (last line)


TODO block 3 line 1
     block 3 line 2
     block 3 line 3
     block 3 line 4
     block 3 line 5 (last line)


TODO block 4 line 1
     block 4 line 2
     block 4 line 3
     block 4 line 4
     block 4 line 5 (last line)


THIS LINE SHOULDN'T BE PRINTED #3
THIS LINE SHOULDN'T BE PRINTED #4
EOF
```

### Output from @Paused's sed script

Unfortunately it is pretty much impossible to get an address range to work for this task.  Too many unwanted lines, and not all of the wanted lines :-(

```sh
sed -n '/^TODO/,/^$/{H;N;/^\n$/{b};p}' <tricky_todo.txt
```

```
TODO block 1 line 1 (last line)


THIS LINE SHOULDN'T BE PRINTED #1
TODO block 2 line 1
     block 2 line 2
     block 2 line 3
     block 2 line 4

     block 2 line 6
TODO block 3 line 1
     block 3 line 2
     block 3 line 3
     block 3 line 4
     block 3 line 5 (last line)


TODO block 4 line 1
```

### Output from my script

**Caveat:** if the TODO block is the last thing in the file, it **MUST** end in two blank lines as specified in the OP or it will be dropped.

```sh
sed -n '/^TODO/{:a;N;s/\n\n$//;Ta;p}' <tricky_todo.txt
```

```
TODO block 1 line 1 (last line)
TODO block 2 line 1
     block 2 line 2
     block 2 line 3
     block 2 line 4

     block 2 line 6
     block 2 line 7
     block 2 line 8 (last line)
TODO block 3 line 1
     block 3 line 2
     block 3 line 3
     block 3 line 4
     block 3 line 5 (last line)
TODO block 4 line 1
     block 4 line 2
     block 4 line 3
     block 4 line 4
     block 4 line 5 (last line)
```

### Tip of the hat to @potong

FWIW, when I came up with the script above, I had somehow overlooked potong's original answer (which had a minor flaw).  When I mentioned it, potong completely rewrote that answer using other strategies.  Because of that and the caveat on my script, I am going to include a corrected version of potong's original answer here:

```sh
sed '/^TODO/!d;:a;$!{N;s/\n\n$//;t;ba}' <tricky_todo.txt
```

### An "awk"ward solution?

Awk is certainly powerful, but I personally tend to use sed because it's more like the beloved vi, which I use on a daily basis.  Nevertheless, here we go:

```sh
awk -vRS="\n\n\n" -vFS="\n" '/TODO/{s=0;for(n=1;n<=NF;n++){if(s==1||$n~/^TODO/){print $n;s=1}}}' <tricky_todo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

use sed for simple substitution.

```
$ more file
1
2
blah blah
TODO
blah blah
4
5


6
7
8
9
10


11
end
$ awk -vRS="\n\n" '/TODO/{print;exit}' file
1
2
blah blah
TODO
blah blah
4
5
```

Comment: He said two consecutive blank lines, not the second blank line encountered. Plus your first one adds a blank line when it prints the first one (before the "4").

Comment: Using `RS` in `awk` is a good idea. You just need another `\n` (`RS="\n\n\n"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'N;/^\n$/q;P;D'
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat double_blank.txt
foo
bar

baz


blah
one
two

three
```

#### Result

```
$ sed 'N;/^\n$/q;P;D' double_blank.txt
foo
bar

baz
```

Comment: This fails if the lines are paired "non-blank/blank" followed by "blank/non-blank". If the second pair is "blank/blank" so there are three blank lines in a row, then it stops one line too late. So the only correct result is if the first pair of blank lines falls on odd/even lines.

Answer (score 0):

Building on SiegeX's answer:

```
cat > lines <<'EOF'
a


c
d
EOF
sed '/^$/N; /^\n$/q' lines
```

Comment: How would you make this work with the OP's range requirement?